# Are datetime-local input types supported in R Shiny at all?

Tags: r, shiny, datetime-local

I'm trying to build a custom datetime-local input in the UI like below.

```
HTML('<input type="datetime-local" max="9999-12-31T23:59" id="test" class="form-control">')
```

It seems like shiny doesn't even detect this kind of input as calling input$test on the server returns NULL. Is there a way to force Shiny to accept this input type without having to resort to external packages?

Comment: Please see [this](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/building-inputs/) and check the paragraph "Write an Input Binding".